# FilmPass in three.js not working

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I am currently just trying to prototype the FilmPass effect in three.js and no matter what I try, I keep receiving the same error messages. I have been on a ton of different websites and I keep coming up with problems.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script src="three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="CopyShader.js"></script>
    <script src="DotScreenShader.js"></script>
    <script src="RGBShiftShader.js"></script>
    <script src="FilmShader.js"></script>
    <script src="FilmPass.js"></script>

    <script src="EffectComposer.js"></script>
    <script src="RenderPass.js"></script>
    <script src="MaskPass.js"></script>
    <script src="ShaderPass.js"></script>


    <script>

        var camera, scene, renderer, composer;
        var object, light;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);

            //

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 400;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x000000, 1, 1000 );

            object = new THREE.Object3D();
            scene.add( object );

            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 4, 4 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );

            for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i ++ ) {

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                mesh.position.set( Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5 ).normalize();
                mesh.position.multiplyScalar( Math.random() * 400 );
                mesh.rotation.set( Math.random() * 2, Math.random() * 2, Math.random() * 2 );
                mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = Math.random() * 50;
                object.add( mesh );

            }

            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );

            // postprocessing

            composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
            // composer.addPass( new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera ) );
            //
            // var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.DotScreenShader );
            // effect.uniforms[ 'scale' ].value = 4;
            // composer.addPass( effect );
            //
            // var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.RGBShiftShader );
            // effect.uniforms[ 'amount' ].value = 0.0015;
            // effect.renderToScreen = true;
            // composer.addPass( effect );



            var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
            composer.addPass(renderPass);

            var effectFilm = new THREE.FilmPass();
            effectFilm.renderToScreen = true;
            composer.addPass(effectFilm);


            var clock = new THREE.Clock()

            function render() {
                var delta = clock.getDelta();
                composer.render(delta); //parameter must be set with render
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
            }
            render();
            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            composer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            object.rotation.x += 0.005;
            object.rotation.y += 0.01;

        //  composer.render();

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Here are the error messages I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending line 38 contains a reference to `THREE.Pass.prototype` which is not defined yet. `THREE.Pass` is defined in `EffectComposer.js`, so you need to put that higher up in your scripts.

```
<script src="EffectComposer.js"></script> <!-- ADD HERE -->
<script src="CopyShader.js"></script>
<script src="DotScreenShader.js"></script>
<script src="RGBShiftShader.js"></script>
<script src="FilmShader.js"></script>
<script src="FilmPass.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="EffectComposer.js"></script> REMOVE HERE -->
<script src="RenderPass.js"></script>
<script src="MaskPass.js"></script>
<script src="ShaderPass.js"></script>
```